# Проблема с подключением произвольного класса

Tags: php, modx

Не понимаю в чём проблема. Есть сниппет, в котором я вызываю свой класс.
при прямом обращении всё ок (/cart/save.html)
А когда через ajax (POST) дергаю эту страницу он говорит, что не может найти класс, который я в том сниппете вызываю

```
Fatal error: Class 'lib\cabinet\User' not found in /var/www/******/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/23.include.cache.php on line 5
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что при POST запросе почему-то не подгружаются классы, а если слать GET запрос, то всё ок.

Answer (score 3):

Если я не ошибаюсь в modx определены константы, MODX_BASE_PATH и т.д. зачем использовать `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` , попробуйте так:

```
require_once(MODX_BASE_PATH.'/lib/cabinet/api.php');
```

А еще помоему в modx что бы обратиться ajax запросом, нужно сначала создать ресурс в админке, по крайней мере в modx >2.2.8

Comment: так если бы проблема была бы с подгрузкой файла была бы соответствующая ошибка . Проблема в том, что почему-то не видит класс

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте так:

```
require_once '../lib/cabinet/api.php';
```